# Is it possible to send out float value with realtime signal?

Tags: c, linux, signals, real-time

So I have two apps in c. First one has to send data to the other, using real-time signals. The data I want to send is float value. As far as I know the only way to send data with rt signal is to use `union sigval` that goes out with it. However, its `sival_int` field is of type int, and the other field is a pointer which I don't think would mean a lot in the other process that gets the signal. I know from my teacher that somehow it is possible, but have no clue how to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Edit: to clarify, my teacher said it is possible to achieve this using realtime signal and `union sigval` and I am curious how.

Comment: Use a pipe and forward the data that way?

Comment: that would work, but unfortunately i am not allowed to do that and have to use real-time signal

Comment: Can you better define "real-time signal"? That takes *many* different forms. Are you talking about `sigevent` specifically? If so maybe you can use a pointer to a `float`, or just slam-cast your `float` into an `int` if `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)` on your ISA.

Comment: @SteveSummit Unfortunately, "Professor Deprecated" is who teaches most C++ courses these days. The last time they read the C++ standard was likely 1998, but some haven't even gotten around to that.

Comment: @tadman It is I who was uninformed, and I've deleted my comment.  I've just learned that Posix "real-time signals" *do* carry values, and therefore your solution of "slam casting" a 32-bit float value would probably work, and is probably the answer Prof. D. expects. The Linux [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page is an interesting read.

Comment: @tadman I send signals using sigqueue. To read the signal, I use sigaction. I hope that is what you meant, I'm quite new to this. Can you clarify what do you mean by slam-casting or what is it exactly?

Comment: @JakubMalinowski An `int` is a 32-bit value, at least, on most machines today.  A `float` is also a 32-bit value, it's just that the bits are interpreted differently.  So if you can contrive to jam the 32 bits of a `float` into an `int`, then send the signal, then extract the bits back into a `float` at the other end, you're done.  You can't use a regular cast, since that would convert the value in a way you don't want; you have to somehow keep the same bit pattern. The `int` value you transmit will be weird, but it should work.

Comment: There are three broad ways of treating one bit pattern as a completely different type, with varying degrees of (in)convenience and (non)portability: (1) using pointers and casts, (2) using unions, (3) using `memcpy`.

Comment: If you're on a machine with 16-bit ints, you might be able to use a [half-precision floating-point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), but then, if you're on a machine with 16-bit ints, you probably don't have Posix real-time signals available.

Comment: I use "slam casting" a bit sarcastically as a normal cast involves careful conversion, like `int x = (int) y` where `float y = 4.9` and you want it converted to a proper `int`. A slam-cast is where you deliberately side-step that conversion and instead just force-reinterpret the raw bits, as in `int x = *((int*) &y)` or an equivalent `memcpy()` to be on the safe side. They don't make it easy to do since it's really quite ugly and can lead to undefined behaviour if you're not very careful about what you're doing and are sure that `sizeof(x) == sizeof(y)`.

Comment: @tadman It's a nice term.  Do you know if it's in widespread use?  (I tried googling it, but all I'm getting is false hits on the cast of the movie Slam (2018). :-( )

Comment: @SteveSummit If we work together we can popularize it! 

Comment: @SteveSummit: Considering that in practice, this is the result of a reinterpret cast, there's not really much demand for a new term.  One should in particular be aware that copying an arbitrary `int` into `float` storage of equal size (using `memcpy` to avoid aliasing violations) still runs the risk of producing a signalling NaN.

Comment: Thanks for all info, it was very helpful! I used memcpy to force my float value into an int and it worked just as i wanted it to. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all current Linux hardware architectures, `sizeof (int) == sizeof (float)` and neither have any padding bits; their storage representations are the same, and type-punning a float to an int and then back to a float always yields the original float (and storage representation).

This means that you need to either copy the storage representation of the float to the int via `memcpy(&value.sival_int, &float, sizeof (int))`, or use an union to type-pun the float and an int (this being an extension supported by GCC, clang, icc, and other C compilers usable in Linux); and then send the signal and value to the target process via `sigqueue()`.

To receive the signal and value, you can either install a signal handler using `sigaction()` (using `.sa_sigaction` for the function pointer, and including `SA_SIGINFO` in `.sa_flags`); or block the signal (via `sigprocmask()`) and catch it explicitly using `sigwaitinfo()` or `sigtimedwait()`.

Comment: Note that while (on these platforms) an int that came from a float can be turned back into a float yielding the same value, if the signal can be delivered from an external source it could bundle a bit pattern that is a signalling NaN and really mess up the unprepared recipient.